# Can't seem to get jquery.dropshadow.js to work on the proper selector?

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

Can't seem to get jquery.dropshadow.js to work on the proper selector. I've tried to select the id and I can't get it to work. I've also tried the class (see below).

### HEAD

```
<script src="scripts/jquery.dropshadow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        $("#tacoFTB").dropShadow({ left: 8, top: 10, opacity: 0.8, blur: 4 });
    }
</script>
```

### HTML

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="backgroundBox">
    <table id="tacoBox" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="520" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td><img src="images/spacer.png" alt="" class="tacoTableColumnSpacer"/></td>
            <td class="tacoBoxMagicFTB" id="tacoFTB"><img src="images/spacer.png" alt="" height="55" width="1"/><img src="images/tb_feedthebeat.png" alt=""/><script type="text/javascript">getLikesFTB('113078108881');</script></td>
            <td><img src="images/spacer.png" alt="" class="tacoTableColumnSpacer"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

### CSS

```
.tacoBoxMagicFTB
{
    background-color: White;
    border:1px solid #b695cb;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
}

.tacoBoxMagicFTB img
{
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need jQuery to apply a shadow anymore, CSS handles it perfectly.

```
#tacoFTB
{
   -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
   box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
}
```

Also, your table doesn't appear to be displaying tabular data, are you using it as a layout tool?

Comment: It might be quick and easy, but it might also be the reason your code doesn't work. Try rebuilding it as a div based layout, that would work much easier with no need for JS.

Comment: This is experimental stage still, yes?  Im not sure it supported in all browsers. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Tables should be used to display tabular data or when there's absolutely no other way to do a layout. Menus can be done perfectly with a floated list, whole page layout work great with a simple grid system. Tables were used in the 90s because CSS was just a nascent technology and there was really no other alternative. Nowadays, there are.

Comment: @CSSHell: It hsa been fully implemented in all modern browsers, IE6,7 and 8 won't have it but you can use http://css3pie.com/ to fix that.

Comment: You solution worked. I am having problems with safari and FF in general but since it works in IE and Chrome I am assuming it will be OK.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This project, is in fact, pulling in data from facebook opengraph and being generated in the table so I guess it's a valid use. I'm old - and old school. :)  Thanks again!